# Simultaneous animation: how to shrink font size while moving left using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Right now I have:

```
$('#title').animate({fontSize:'20px'},200).animate({marginLeft:'0'},200);
```

Which reduces the font size and then moves left. Is there a way to execute these animations simultaneously - as in, the title starts moving left and on the way the font size get smaller?

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind...

```
function shrinktitle() {
    $("#title").animate({
       fontSize:'20px',
       marginLeft:'0'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
}
```